# How do I get the NMEA data from a serial GPS connected to my android device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, serial-port

I am working on a project where I have to connect my android device to a GPS with usb. I can't figure out how I can get the data out of my GPS and I do not want to use the device it's internall GPS because I need to be pretty accurate. I have read the tutorial on the android website and I have tried to work with it but I still do not understand how I have to make connection to the GPS.
Here is my code.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("deviceName");


private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device =    (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if  (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)){
                    if(device != null){
                        //roep hier de method aan om communicatie met he apparaat te maken
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: show some progress in your question. what do you get from tutorial

Comment: I have posted the code for you sir

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give this a shot: http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/. Captures all serial data, does not require rooting. You would need to use Service. Let us know if you need more help. I have done this before, not on Android though.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir but I have already tried to work with this website and it did not work out for me...

Comment: Did you rx (receive) anything at all? Check for baudrate. It's usually 9600 kbps.

Comment: You also might want to use these apps first to verify if the connection is taking place correctly: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oneman.freeusbtools&hl=en or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android_serialport_api.sample&hl=en

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment but we have tried Usb Serial Terminal lite and we got data from it. But what we want is to make this in our own project and we do not know how we should make the connection and retrieve the data from the GPS.

Comment: Suggest you compile and run this: http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/source/browse/#git%2FUsbSerialExamples, then send us the logs

Comment: I have just tried the code from  http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/ but it does not recognize "UsbSerialDriver". Do you have any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Sorry, but can't be of help. The logs might have been of help. It could be that the device filter xml is not being interpreted as required.